# How to enable autocomplete in <input > with <label ><input ><button >

Tags: javascript, html

I am not web developer, but I have a task to add autocomplete function for an input box. Please treat me as a very beginner.

```
<div>
  <label id="email_label" for="send_email" style="padding-right:5px">
    Send Email:
  </label>
  <input id="send_email" type="text" placeholder="e.g. xx.yy@zz.com" />
  <button id="ack" onclick="requestAck()">
    Request
  </button>
</div>
```

requestAck() is a javascript function sending a email to address given by user (i.e. address in `<input >`). I am trying to add a flag in `<input autocomplete="on" ...>`, but it doesn't work. Perhaps because it's not in a `<form></form>` environment.

Could you help me to modify this code adding autocomplete (from cache) without changing other functions. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the property `name="email"` on the input tag, without that set the browser doesn't know what's supposed to autocomplete the field with :)

**protip**: I warmly suggest you to set the type of the input to email with `type="email"` instead of text, it's not required but it will help validating the input!

check this code:

```
        <div>
            <label id="email_label" for="send_email" style="paddingright:5px">Send Email:</label>
            <input id="send_email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="e.g. xx.yy@zz.com" />
            <button id="ack" onclick="requestAck()">Request</button>
        </div>
```

**EDIT: Final solution discussed in comments**

```
<form onsubmit="submitForm(event)">
  <label id="email_label" for="send_email" style="padding-right:5px">Send Email:</label>
  <input id="send_email" type="email" autocomplete="email" name="email" placeholder="e.g. xx.yy@zz.com" />
  <button id="ack" type="submit">Request</button>
</form>
<script>
  function submitForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // this prevents the page from reloading
    requestAck();
  }

  //dummy function so the javascript won't crash:
  function requestAck() {}
</script>
```

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-cray-ubkw4

Comment: thanks. add type check is a nice suggestion! however, it cannot help with the autocomplete, which should only depend on the historical input.

Comment: have you set up the name property too? the browser matches the historical inputs with the name property on the inputs.. I have set up a working example here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-dew-f0w2h

does it work for you? If not may I ask you what system/browser are you working on?

Comment: The example "partially" works. The problem is you cannot update the tag list. For example, you enter bob@gmail.com, and you click request. When you reload the page, bob@gmail.com cannot be popped. I think the problem is "the button doesn't link to the input" unlike the example here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_button_form However, i don't know how to translate my code in this format...

Comment: ok, so the question wasn't clear to me.. you want to write an email address, click submit and then have the email to remain in the input field?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. What I need is like google search box, say you enter bob@gmail.com in the first time and you click submit. At the second time you write tom@gmail.com and submit. Next time you open this page, the search box should suggest you bob@gmail.com and tom@gmail.com (and other address you've used) in the recommendation list. You may also check https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp

Comment: I've been thinking a while and the problem might be that you are not actually submitting any form, so the browser doesn't cache the emails..

I have made another example where I am now firing an actual submit event, so the browser can acknowledge the submission. inside the submit event it will call the requestAck function:

https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-cray-ubkw4

Comment: nice solution! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, I've updated the answer with this solution!

Comment: @Weizhi - per my comment on Nidhin's answer, you could actually set `autocomplete="email"` to hint to the browser that it is previously entered email addresses that should be considered for completion. See the [allowed values](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete#Values) for the autocomplete attribute.

Comment: @StephenP that's a nice point, I didn't want to overload the post creator with informations though.. I found out yesterday that autocomplete accepts more values that just on|off, this attribute is very useful and I will make sure to make use of it in future projects!